# install4j - Radio Buttons for Installation Components

Tags: install4j

I want to make user select only one component. Is there a way to do this?
Install4j provides only check boxes, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go one level higher, to *installation types*. Add the "Installation type" screen to your installer and customize the installation types on the screen. Each installation type defines the installation components that should be installed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ingel. I dont understand. How can this give me radio buttons. In the screen shot you showed me, I want user to install either Hellow world or Source files. Not both.

Comment: @Aragorn Then add two installation types, one with "Hello world application" selected and the other with "Source files" selected.